# Spring 4 how to programmatically fetch and register new beans at runtime?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, applicationcontext, spring-4

I have an application which sends messages over JMS that was running Spring 3.2 and was upgraded to Spring 4.2.

What the application was doing in certain circumstances was setting up a single GenericApplicationContext in a utility class, and fetching and registering beans without first registering every single bean first.

Example:

```
        final BeanDefinitionBuilder bDBuilder = BeanDefinitionBuilder
                .rootBeanDefinition("org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate");

        if (connectionFactoryBeanName == null) {
            bDBuilder.addPropertyValue("connectionFactory", connectionFactory);
        } else {
            bDBuilder.addPropertyValue("connectionFactory",
                    genericContext.getBean(connectionFactoryBeanName));
        }

        if (jmsDestinationBeanName == null) {
            bDBuilder.addPropertyValue("defaultDestination", destination);
        } else {
            bDBuilder.addPropertyValue("defaultDestination",
                    genericContext.getBean(jmsDestinationBeanName));
        }

        genericContext.registerBeanDefinition(location,
                bDBuilder.getBeanDefinition());
```

When the following line was executed:

```
genericContext.getBean(jmsDestinationBeanName));
```

I get an exception that says:

```
 org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext has not been refreshed yet
```

This issue only started occurring after the upgrade from spring-tx (and all other spring) 3.2 to spring 4.2. If I switch the version back the problem goes away.

When I try placing

```
genericContext.refresh();
```

after or before any bean registrations on the context it throws an exception stating multiple refresh attempts aren't allowed.

What can be done in Spring 4 to allow this kind of behavior and "hot" refreshing of the application context?

Comment: Are you using xml config or java base?

Comment: @KenBekov XML based as the beans are defined in a beans.xml class